# Почему вывод print() при использовании time.sleep выводит без задержек?

Tags: python, время, print

```
import time
i = 1

def anp(s):
    lens = len(s)
    g = 0
    for i in range(lens):
        print(s[g], end="")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        g += 1

anp('Привет')
```

Если запускаю в Python Shell, то программа работает корректно - выводит надпись по буквам с задержкой в 0.1 сек.. Но если запустить её же в онлайн-компиляторе или в любом другом (консоль, PyCharm и т.д.), то выводит сплошной текст без задержек между буквами.

В чём ошибка, почему оно по разному работает в разных программах?

Ссылка на [онлайн-компилятор](https://repl.it/languages/python3).

Comment: Сейчас пробывал в sublime text, все работает правильно, в онлайн компиляторе сначало получается результат, а потом выводится, в pycharm и idle когда увеличил задержку на 0.5 все нормально. Возможно это из-за того что эти интерпритаторы работают быстрее обычной консоли и результат приходит моментально. Просто поставьте задержку побольше и все будет хорошо. UPD: Сейчас погуглил разные онлайн компиляторы, и все они работают одинаково, сначало ждут результата потом выводят.

Answer (score 3):

Вывод может буферизироваться (то есть сначала накапливается некоторый кусок данных, потом целиком выводится) - особенно если вывод идет в файл, но бывает что и вывод в консоль буферизируется.

Если нужно чтобы каждый символ сразу выводился, можно использовать параметр `flush` функции `print`:

```
print(s[g], end="", flush=True)
```

Или вызывать метод `.flush()` для файлового объекта, в который идет вывод. При выводе на консоль это `sys.stdout`:

```
import sys

...

    for i in range(lens):
        print(s[g], end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        g += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте в IPython и добавте параметр flush, чтобы сбрасывать буфер вывода в консоль, увидите, что работает. Буферизация вывода происходит на системном уровне, и если есть задержки вывода, то это не ошибка Python или вашей программы.

```
In [9]: import time
   ...: i = 1
   ...:
   ...: def anp(s):
   ...:     lens = len(s)
   ...:     g = 0
   ...:     for i in range(lens):
   ...:         print(s[g], end="", flush=True)
   ...:         time.sleep(0.1)
   ...:         g += 1
   ...:

In [10]: anp('123456789')
123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import time


def anp(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print(s[i], end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)


anp('Привет')
```

Просто добавьте в строку кода с `print` "`flush=True`", это очистит буфер. И, да, тут вполне можно обойтись без переменных `lens` и `g`.