# Python. Можно ли сделать задержку для вывода текста?

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите, возможно ли на одной строке сделать задержку вывода текста? Или же существует какой-то обход? Если да, то как его сделать?
Пример текста:
`print("Или... (возможная задержка) Это шутка, которую я не понимаю?")`

Comment: Разделите строку на две и между ними поставьте нужный time.sleep

Comment: @andreymal Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Comment: @nomnoms12 увы нет

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Проблема с print при использовании time.sleep](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1083266/1365)

Answer (score 1):

Разделите строку на две и между ними поставьте нужный `time.sleep`.

***Пример:***

```py
from time import sleep

print('Или... ', end='', flush=True)
sleep(2)  # где 2 — задержка в секундах
print('Это шутка, которую я не понимаю?')
```

***stdout:***

```py
Или... Это шутка, которую я не понимаю?
```